# How to display specific parts of an object using a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm making a Trivia game and have an object full of questions and answers. I want to display the first question and the choices users have on the screen. After they guess, the program displays the second question.

This is what I have so far:

```
var qAndA = {
  q1: {
    question: "What is the capital of nevada",
    choices:["Reno","Carson City","Las Vegas", "Boulder City"]
  },
  q2:{
    question: "What is the capital of Oregon?",
    choices:["Salem","Portland","Eugene","Bend"]
  },
  q3:{
    question: "What is the capital of Vermont?",
    choices:["Burlington","Bennington","Stowe","Montpelier"]
  },
};

function questionsAnswers(){
  timer();
  //This Is Where I want To Use A Loop Rather Than Writing Out ".q1.question"
  $("#main").append(qAndA.q1.question);
}
```

Is there a way to target a specific object in the array without having to write `qAndA.q1.question` so I don't have to write it out for each individual question *(Perhaps some sort of loop to do this)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in objects can also be referenced using the array notation, which treats the key name as plain strings:

```
var myObj = {
    key1: 'a',
    key2: 'b',
    key3: 'c'
}


console.log(myObj.key1) // 'a'
console.log(myObj["key1"]) // 'a'
console.log(myObj["key" + "1"]) // 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-writing qAndA.q1.question as `qAndA.["q"+i].question` as dynamic as possible.
You can assign `"q"+i` to a `var` and append it to the above expression. This expression shall be in a loop :

```
var size = Object.keys(qAndA).length;

for (var i=1;i<=size ;i++){
  var c= "q"+i; //q1 when i=1 and so on
  // do ur routine stuff
  //qAndA["q"+i] === qAndA[c]
}
```